# Vue-cli : ERROR Error: command failed: npm install --loglevel error --legacy-peer-deps

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

When I try to create a new project (vue create my-project), I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-14T16_48_04_209Z-debug-0.log
 **ERROR**  Error: command failed: npm install --loglevel error --legacy-peer-deps
Error: command failed: npm install --loglevel error --legacy-peer-deps
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\lib\util\executeCommand.js:138:16)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at cp.emit (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)
```

I'm on PC / Windows 10, and updated vue/cli, node, and npm.
Persets: ([Vue 3] dart-sass, babel, router, vuex, unit-jest).

I updated vue/cli, node, npm, and yarn.
I search for a solution here, and tried these  solutions:

- npm cache clean --force
- npm config set registry="http://registry.npmjs.org/"
- vue config --set useTaobaoRegistry false
- npm config set fetch-retry-mintimeout 20000   (This did't work).
- npm config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout 120000    (This did't work).

But the error is still when creating a project.

After the Internet acceleration procedures, the packages were downloaded, but this error remained:

> npm ERR! Invalid Version:

> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\npm-cache_logs\2023-01-16T19_19_07_037Z-debug-0.log

> **ERROR**  Error: command failed: npm install --loglevel error --legacy-peer-deps
>
> Error: command failed: npm install --loglevel error --legacy-peer-deps

> at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli\lib\util\executeCommand.js:138:16)
> at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at cp.emit (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
> at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
> at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)

Comment: What does the error log say at `C:\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-14T16_48_04_209Z-debug-0.log`? As an aside the vue-cli is being replaced by vite and new projects are recommended to be scaffolded with vite.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know.

Comment: What is vite, does it belong to vue?

Comment: Vite is the new scaffolding tool for vue.js. It's what will be used moving forward while `vue-cli` will eventually be deprecated. Its built by the Vue.js devs and should be faster for larger projects.

Comment: Are you running a VPN or is your connection going through a proxy server? Is your internet connection stable? What version of npm are you using? Do you have a `yarn.lock` and/or `package-lock.json` file? Have you tried with `npx`?  Since you're on windows are you running your console as administrator? Did you set a proxy in npm?